# APP based on camera2 API crash in certain devices due to an Image Reader surface

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera2

I am having one of these mysterious android' issues (at least from my point of view). My app manages the device's camera via the camera2 api library. In my case I have two surfaces, one of them coming from an Image Reader object. Next I define my capture session and set those surfaces as targets. As you can see in the code below, I am following the typical workflows in such cases:

```
        // Create ImageReader Surface
        int max = 2;
        mReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth, mHeight, ImageFormat.YV12, max);
        ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader mReader) {
                Image image = null;
                image = mReader.acquireLatestImage();
                if (image == null) {
                    return;
                }                           

                byte[] bytes = convertYUV420ToNV21(image);

                nativeVideoFrame(bytes);
                image.close();   
            }
        };

        if (OPENGL_SOURCE==2){
            nativeVideoInit(mWidth, mHeight, 0, false);
        }

        mReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);

        // Create Texture Surface
        texture = createTexture();
        mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(texture);
        mSurfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);
        mSurfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
        mSurface = new Surface(mSurfaceTexture);

        //Attach surfaces to CaptureRequest
        List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(2);
        outputSurfaces.add(mReader.getSurface());
        outputSurfaces.add(mSurface);
        captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(mSurface);
        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(mReader.getSurface());

        //Define the capture request
        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        //The camera is already closed
                        if (null == cameraDevice) {
                            return;
                        }
                        // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                        cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                        updatePreview();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Configuration change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The thing is that I am not having any problem running this code on my tablet Samsung TAB A. However, when trying in my Nexus 5X or my friend's Samsung S6, the app crashes dramatically throwing this error:

08-23 11:28:51.772: E/AndroidRuntime(20315): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 11:28:51.772: E/AndroidRuntime(20315): Process: com.example.opengltest, PID: 20315
08-23 11:28:51.772: E/AndroidRuntime(20315): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad argument passed to camera service
08-23 11:28:51.772: E/AndroidRuntime(20315):    at android.hardware.camera2.utils.CameraBinderDecorator.throwOnError(CameraBinderDecorator.java:114)

Doing some test, I found that the problem comes from the image reader surface. If I get rid off on this surface from the capture session's settings, the code runs seamlessly.

Why is this happening only on my Nexus 5x or Samsung S6 and not in my tablet? And how can I fix it?

Thanks,

JM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the whole system logcat, the camera service should have a 
more detailed line that states why your output surface set is bad.

However, YV12 is not a format that's guaranteed to be supported, so it's probably just that. Some devices support it, some don't.

The only YUV format that's guaranteed to be supported by all devices is [ImageFormat.YUV_420_888](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YUV_420_888).

If you want to use YV12 when possible, you'll need to check the [StreamConfigurationMap.getOutputFormats()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap.html#getOutputFormats()) list to see if it's listed before trying to use it. But you'll still need to fall back to YUV_420_888 on many devices, so it's simplest to just support that directly and nothing else.

Comment: It was exactly what you said. Those devices didn't support YV12 format